# как проверить значение на undefined в catch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

res.response.data.message выдает undefuned в data
даже так ошибка

```
typeof res.response.data.message === 'undefined' ? ' res.response.data.message ' : 'error'
```

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var useMessage = res && res.response && res.response.data && 
  typeof res.response.data.message != 'undefined';
var message = useMessage ? res.response.data.message : 'error';
```